# Convert today date into UTC string

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to convert today date to UTC. Even though I used .toISOString() to change the time. I used

```
import {formatDate} from '@angular/common';
```

```
today = formatDate(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss', 'en');
```

How can I convert today in UTC format? Plz advise me

Comment: Try `new Date().toUTCString();`.

Comment: @Mridul I tried with ```today = formatDate(new Date().toUTCString(), 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss', 'en'); ```

output: ```2020-06-16 12:48:49```  ...But this is not converting to UTC

Comment: You want to convert into UTC but display according to your specified format?

Comment: @Mridul I have tried with this and get UTC time ```nowDate = new Date().toISOString();```

output ```2020-06-16T04:51:25.565Z``` . Mainly I want in this format  ```2020-06-16T04:51:25.565Z```

Comment: toISOString creates the same output as the one you want doesn't it?  It's not clear what you are asking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular Docs:
[formatDate](https://angular.io/api/common/formatDate)
[DatePipe (format string) docs](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)
Use the timezone third parameter:

```
import {formatDate} from '@angular/common';
today = formatDate(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss', 'en', '+0000'); 

console.log(formatDate(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZZZZZ', 'en', 'GMT'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One thing I want to be clear is, how can I make this formate ```2020-06-16T04:51:25.565Z```?

Comment: That's just toISOString isn't it?  The other answer has that output on the third line

Comment: Do you just mean adding a timezone onto the end in ISO style?  like the above?  Is there a reason you can't just use toISOString?

Comment: Thank you I got your answer is useful. Thnx.

Answer (score 1):

What I could understand from your question is that you want something like this

```js
let d = new Date().toUTCString();
console.log(d);
console.log(new Date(d).toISOString());
```